# Regex Expression to get everything between double quotes

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a regex to work for a string of multiline text. Need this to work for python.

Example text:

```
description : "4.10 TCP Wrappers - not installed"
info        : "If some of the services running in /etc/inetd.conf are 

required, then it is recommended that TCP Wrappers are installed and configured to limit access to any active TCP and UDP services.

TCP Wrappers allow the administrator to control who has access to various inetd network services via source IP address controls. TCP Wrappers also provide logging information via syslog about both successful and unsuccessful connections.

TCP Wrappers are generally triggered via /etc/inetd.conf, but other options exist for \"wrappering\" non-inetd based software.

The configuration of TCP Wrappers to suit a particular environment is outside the scope of this benchmark; however the following links will provide the necessary documentation to plan an appropriate implementation:

ftp://ftp.porcupine.org/pub/security/index.html

The website contains source code for both IPv4 and IPv6 versions."

expect      : "^[\\s]*[A-Za-z0-9]+:[\\s]+[^A][^L][^L]"
required        : YES
```

I have come up with this,

```
[(a-zA-Z_ \t#)]*[:][ ]*\"[^\"]*.*\"
```

But the problem is that it stops at the second \" the rest of the line is not selected.

My objective is to get the entire string starting from info till the end of the double quotes, relating to the info line.

This same regex should also work for the 'expect' line, starting from expect ending at the double quotes relating to the expect string.

Once I get the entire string I will split it on the first ":" because I want to store these strings into a DB with the "description", "info", "expect" as columns then the strings as values in those columns.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Your regex starts matching at `tester : `, but the title implies it's supposed to match between double quotes, so I'm not sure what the expected output is. Does `"(?:\\.|[^"])*"` do what you want?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @Rawing your solution works after I combine it with my starting regex to get [(a-zA-Z_ \t#)]*[:][ ]*"(?:\\.|[^"])*" Could you explain a little on how it works?

Comment: @Rawing  Ah, sorry , it broke, I have a line like this group : "@GROUP@" || "test" It didn't capture || "test"

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use thelexer provided in the `shlex` module:

```
>>> s = """tester : "this is a long string
that
is multiline, contains \\" double qoutes \\" and .
this line is finished\""""
>>> shlex.split(s[s.find('"'):])[0]
'this is a long string\nthat\nis multiline, contains " double qoutes " and .\nthis line is finished'
```

It will also remove the backslases from the double quotes inside the string.

The code finds the first double quote in the string and only looks at the string starting from there.  It then uses `shlex.split()` to tokenize the remainder of the string, and takes the first token from the returned list.

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for your input, I have amended the question, because my sample data is actually a lot more than just one line.

Comment: @d123: The method described here can easily be used for multiline data as well.  Just do `shlex.split(s)` and look at all the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1:** I got this to work:

```
[(a-zA-Z_ \t#)]*[:][ ]*\"([^\"]|(?<=\\\\)[\"])*\"
```

**Update 2:** If you cannot modify the file to add escaped quotes where necessary for the expression above, then as long as the lines such as

```
group : "@GROUP@" || "test"
```

exist only as single lines, then I think this will grab those along with the longer quoted values:

```
[(a-zA-Z_ \t#)]*[:][ ]*(?:\"([^\"]|(?<=\\\\)[\"])*\"|.*)(?=(?:\r\n|$))
```

Try that, and if it works, I'll update again to explain it.

Comment: If I add the question mark, it will stop at the first \"

Comment: I have amended my answer with a solution that worked for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: whoa, it works. But I cannot understand why it works, could you explain a little on what is happening?

Comment: Ah, sorry , it broke, I have a line like this group : "@GROUP@" || "test" It didn't capture || "test"

Comment: @d123, you need to surround with quotes and escape the inner quotes: "\"@GROUP@\" || \"test\"" Regex is good, but your input has to be consistent. I'll update my answer with an explanation when I get to my box later.

Comment: @d123, I edited my post with an updated regex. See if that works better. If it does what you need, I'll edit again to explain.